# Parse dynamic valueType from API call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json-deserialization

I am working on an 3rd party implementation to our site. The API that I am calling on code returns an unique value pair.

```json
ValueType: //code, percent, money
Value: //depending on ValueType can be string, int, or object { currency: string, amount: decimal }
```

I am trying to put my head on it but can't seem to find a proper way to parse it on a C# object other that having `enum` and `object`.

```cs
public class ReturnType
{
    public EnumValueType ValueType { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public enum EnumValueType
{
    MONEY,
    PERCENT,
    CODE
}
```

This makes it harder to access `Value`. I am looking for another solution.

Any suggestions for POCO class to parse it in a proper way would be appreciated.

Comment: This is how I have done it similarly in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make 3 methods and use overloading (same method name, 3 different signatures), 1 that takes lets say string/enum and string, 1 that takes string/enum and int, and for the last one, string/enum and for the object make a new class and define currency: string, amount: decimal properties and make it accept that. I dont know if I helped, but there you go...